# Rails: Bootstrap and container width different for certain row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

My application is set up such that my application.html.erb is as follows:

```
<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}") %>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
</body>
```

This means that every view that I have is within the container class, which limits the width to whatever the default is for bootstrap 2.x!  This is fine for everything I have done so far but on a particular view I have some rows that I really want to take up the full screen width, but I am not sure how to go about doing that.  I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

In my view:

```
<div id="full-row">
  my view here
</div>
```

In my custom.css file I have the following:

```
#full-row{
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

This is probably something quite basic but CSS is not my strong point by any means.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone help on this? I'm sure it's something quick to do but would really appreciate some help :)

Comment: Anyone? I'm still struggling with this.  Would really appreciate the help.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this working so I basically re-designed the views such that I controller when I used the container class and didn't.  I guess that was an easier solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to solve this issue in the end.

In my custom.css I created the following:

```
.container-wide{
  max-width: 1980px;
  min-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
}
```

In addition to the above, I changed the views so that I removed the  line from my application.html.erb file and instead opened and closed the div in each view and used the container-wide when needed.